# Represent Enum values as String

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, enums

I have this  Enum

```
Public Enum HotkeyModifiers As Short
    SHIFT = 1
    CONTROL = 2
    ALT = 4
    NONE = 0
End Enum
```

So `6` is equals to `ALT+CONTROL`, so when I do this:

```
 MsgBox((HotkeyModifiers.CONTROL Or HotkeyModifiers.ALT).ToString)
MsgBox([Enum].Parse(GetType(HotkeyModifiers), 6).ToString)
```

I expect to get this output as String:

```
CONTROL, ALT
```

Because If I try to do the same with a framework enum like for example the `Keys` enum:

```
MsgBox((Keys.Alt Or Keys.ControlKey).ToString)
```

I get this string:

```
ControlKey, Alt
```

Then what I'm missing to do in my Enumeration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decorate your enum with [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).

```
<Flags>
Public Enum HotkeyModifiers As Short
    SHIFT = 1
    CONTROL = 2
    ALT = 4
    NONE = 0
End Enum
```

That affects the behaviour of both `ToString` and parsing.

Comment: Thankyou, solved!, but I should use flags or flagsattribute? intellisense says the same for both and also I can't find the difference

Comment: @ElektroStudios: They're the same - when you specify an attribute, the `Attribute` suffix is implicit (but can be specified explicitly too).

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have no issues when doing like the following:

```
    Private Enum enumModul As Integer
        Modul_1 = 1
        Modul_2 = 2
        Modul_3 = 3
        Out_of_work = 4
        Pause = 5
    End Enum

    Dim Modul As enumModul = 0

    Label3.Text = Modul.ToString
```